# Convert hex string to bigint in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, hex, postgresql-9.1

I'd like to convert a hex string as used by HTML into a `bigint` to then convert it into separate R, G and B values in Postgres via a function written in PL/pgSQL.

I can decode the string into `bytea` like this:

```
hex bytea := decode(hex, 'hex');
```

And in a query with fixed values this works like a beauty:

```
select ( array[ (cast(x'ffaa33' as bigint) >> 16) % 256,
                (cast(x'ffaa33' as bigint) >> 8) % 256,
                 cast(x'ffaa33' as bigint) % 256 ] )
```

But I can't put the two together, passing - for example *'ffaa33'* as parameter.

Anyone got a better idea? I'm using PosgreSQL 9.1?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An easy way is:

```
 select ('x'||lpad(the_hex_value,16,'0'))::bit(64)::bigint;
```

The left padding with 0 is necessary because the leftmost bit is always going to be interpreted as the sign bit.
Also keep in mind that `bigint` is signed, postgres doesn't have built-in unsigned types.

Comment: thanks Daniel.  How to do bigint to hex?

Comment: @Cherven: postgres has a builtin `to_hex(bigint)` function